# Spotify - passing a list as parameter

Tags: python, list, parameters, spotipy

I have a function to be called later in a `for` loop.

```
def show_tracks(results):
    for i, item in enumerate(tracks['items']):
        track = item['track']
        print("   %d %32.32s %s" % (i, track['artists'][0]['name'], track['name']))
```

2nd snippet:

```
playlists = sp.user_playlists(username) #spotipy method
for playlist in playlists['items']:
    if playlist['owner']['id'] == username:
        print()
        print(playlist['name'])
        print('  total tracks', playlist['tracks']['total'])
        results = sp.user_playlist(username, playlist['id'], fields="tracks,next")
        tracks = results['tracks']
        show_tracks(tracks)                
        while tracks['next']:
            tracks = sp.next(tracks)
            show_tracks(tracks)
```

but now I would like to pass a `list` of usernames, like so:

```
    playlists = sp.user_playlists(#list of usernames)
```

I have tried to define the second snippet as a function, but in doing so an issue of global vs local variables showed up:

`NameError: global name 'tracks' is not defined`

So, how do I pass a list of `usernames` and loop though each one of them?

Comment: can `results['tracks']` happen to be empty?

Comment: @BediEgilmez no, it returns valid `JSON` data structure

Answer (score 0):

Check your `show_tracks(results)` function. You are not passing results anywhere.

Additionally you are iterating over tracks which is not defined in that function. Simply replace `tracks` with `results`. Then you are good to go.

Comment: the code is working...`tracks` is being passed as parameter `results`. what I haven't achieved is how to pass a list to `(usernames)`

Comment: No, your function is wrong. You are not using `results` in your `show_tracks` function!

Comment: I got the code from plamere's `spotipy`'s `git` https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/examples/user_playlists_contents.py. mind you he created the whole wrapper. It can't be wrong. I get results...

Comment: I got rid of `show_track` function and added its code to th end of `get_playlist_tracks`. with an extra function to retrieve all `id`'s, it is looping now through all `users`. thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't know who wrote it but that function IS wrong.